# a question about grammar and syntax

Tags: syntax, english, grammar, syntax-trees

[image]

can anyone provide me a short critique for the following analyses of the sentence. About their advantages and disadvantages and provide evidence if possible!!thank you.

I have no idea about this.

Comment: Where did it come from and what is it for?

Comment: To me this is a catenative construction with the uppermost VP being _might have been watching television_ and each successive lower clause a catenative complement.

Comment: The tree is pretty meaningless as it is. Some of the constituents correctly have two labels assigned to them (category + function) while others don't.

Comment: @BillJ Which nodes in the tree have two labels? I understand the stacked labels as unary branching. Normally, the category + function shouldn't need to be encoded as distinct labels, but follow from the constituent name and its hierarchical position in the tree (like PP: category = prepositional, function = verbal modifier because it is combined with the VP as an adjunction).

Comment: @uiheng ung You'd really need to tell us which precise theory you are assuming, or what textbook you are using. Otherwise there is no way we will be able to check whether you met your theory-specific requirements (e.g., I have never seen "M" as a category for modal verbs, but without any information about your assumptions I can't tell whether your theory does have this category or whether you just did something wrong in your tree).

Comment: @lemontree I skimmed it too quickly. None of them have.

Comment: @Bill This is not a precise theory it just a question of my grammar class. I was asked to answer this question but I have no idea to answer it. The tree diagram is analyze by my professor. I still can't figure out what's the advantages and disadvantage if the sentence analyze like this.

Comment: @lemontree It was introduced at least as early as Falk (1984), the precursor to IP. Falk assumed that M headed S.

Comment: I see. The tree I drew in my answer below represented the way it would it be shown in modern general purpose grammar where the auxiliaries are catenative verbs heading catanative clauses.

Comment: And here we have the reason why we don't like questions about grammar trees. Anybody can make them up and present them as standard, even when they are full of mistakes and incorrect presuppositions. There is no ISO standard for English grammar trees. For instance, a tree that would satisfy me would strike @BillJ as sloppy and most improper, and his proper trees would strike me as full of useless epicycles; but we both think the tree your teacher gave out is not much use in helping you or anybody else to think about English grammar.

Comment: I think it comes from here: http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~gawron/syntax/midterm/midterm.htm That's true that the question is not precise enough to understand what is the precise point you didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn how to use diagnostics to tell you whether you have the right structure.  One such diagnostic is provided by "and", which connects constituents of the same category.  In the tree you give, "might have been watching television" is not a constituent.  Yet we can form:

```
He [[might have been watching television] and [has no idea what happened]].
```

That tells us that "might have been watching television" is actually a constituent which has the same category as "has no idea what happened".

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Tree Diagram - Catenative Construction Assumed.

[image]